# How do I make a fileset from a comma-separated list of directories in Ant?

Tags: ant, fileset

In an Ant target I get a property, containing the list of directories to be included in further action (copying, filtering, etc.). It looks like this:

```
directories=dir1, dir2, dir3
```

I need a way to convert this list to a fileset or patternset that selects **all** the files in these directories.

I know I can use a script to generate pattern strings and then use it in the "include" or "exclude", but is there are a way to avoid scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of Ant 1.9.4, there is a new construct [<multirootfileset>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/multirootfileset.html) that provides that functionality, even if the dirs are not siblings:

```
<multirootfileset basedirs="${directories}" includes="**/*">
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the antcontrib [`propertyregex`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) task to convert the comma-separated list into wildcards suitable for a fileset?

```
<property name="directories" value="dir1, dir2, dir3" />

<property name="wildcard" value="${file.separator}**${file.separator}*" />
<propertyregex property="my_pattern"
               input="${directories}" 
               regexp=", " 
               replace="${wildcard}," />
```

At this point we now have:

```
my_pattern=dir1/**/*,dir2/**/*,dir3
```

That can be used with a further suffixed wildcard to get the full fileset:

```
<fileset dir="." id="my_fileset" includes="${my_pattern}${wildcard}" />
```

(The fiddly `${wildcard}` is to ensure portability between unix and windows filesystems, you could use `/**/*` if you're pure unix.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<dirset includes="${directories}"/>
```

Yes, `dirset` isn't `fileset`.  However, it may be enough, or else you can probably use a `for` or `foreach` from ant-contrib to iterate over the directories in your target.  You might also be able to define a ResourceCollection based around the dirset.  It might help to know what the "further action" is expected to be.

However, this feels like too much work ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, however, as you noticed this is too much work. Using script to convert list to pattern is more concise. 

I can switch to semicolon-delimited list, but why this should make any difference?

Comment: Yah, I guess it doesn't make that much difference.  It seems like it should be possible to do something with a <restrict> resource collection, but I wasn't able to get it to work: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#restrict